# What is a fair trade for a Paladin's mount in exchange for alternate abilities, feats, and skills?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, class-feature, paladin

I never use my mount for my level six swordsman/archer paladin, and I need a good idea to approach the DM with He offered me a bonus feat instead — is that fair?

Answer (score 22):

[This post](https://minmaxforum.com/index.php?topic=8732.0) contains all alternative class features published by WotC. Here are the mount replacements listed there, along with sources:

> - Charging Smite (*Player’s Handbook II*, p 53): No special mount, if you smite on a charge attack, gain 2 extra damage per paladin level.
> - Divine Spirit (*Dungeonscape*, p 11): No special mount. Gain a spirit that grants special abilities to you and/or your allies.
> - Lion Legionaire (*Champions of Valor*, p 44): Flying Lion (*fly* 1/day), replaces special mount.
> - Stand Fast ([*Cityscape* online web enhancement “Urban Class Features”](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112031718/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/we/20070228a)): Do not gain special mount. Add your divine grace bonus to allies' saving throws. Also gain the ability to add the bonus to rolls to resist bullrush, grapple, trips, sunders, and disarms.
> - Underdark Knight (*Complete Champion*, p 49): Lose special mount. Gain low-light vision, and a bonus to Climb, Jump, and Balance. At 7th level, gain *spike stones*. At 12th level gain earth glide. At 15th level gain *dimension door*.

Depending on the rulebooks you use, these may be more desirable. Given how feat-starved most characters are in 3.5, though, I'd say this is a fair trade, and it does seem to be about on-par with the ones here.