# Replacing a Samurais "Mounted Archer" class feature

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, class-feature

Following up on my question about [replacing a samurais mount](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/63709/replacement-for-a-samurai-mount-in-a-dungeon-crawler), I took a look at the features a samurai has and thought about his *Weapons Expertise*, which allows him to choose a weapon from a very limited list. Seeing as his *mounted archer* class feature is actually a feat, I thought about giving him the following to replace *mounted archer*:

- Free *Weapon Focus* with the selected weapon
- Free *Weapon Specialization* with the selected weapon, if he already has the *Weapon Focus*

Would this be in any way considered an overpowered replacement? Also, as a side-question: Do you think it fits the style of the class?

Comment: "Overpowered" is a completely subjective term. While your replacement is vastly superior to the original feat, there is no way for us to tell if it is overpowered or not unless you first explain what you would consider overpowered.

Comment: You are completely right about that. nvoigt gave a good answer to my question regardless, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mounted Archery is a feat that is very situational. When you play a Steppe Nomad campaign it's probably the greatest thing since sliced bread, for all other campaigns it's basically a dead slot.

Your two replacements are feats that work reliably on every single attack (or damage) roll.

On average, over all possible campaign types, the replacements feats are way more powerful.

Are they *over*powered? That can only be answered based on *your* specific campaign and players.

Personally, I don't think of them as overpowered with my players in my campaigns, but your perception might be different.

However, are they a good replacement? You replace a seldom used feat that shines the one time it's used with something that is always good but will never actually be mentioned as a feat.

You may want to look for something that captures this feeling of being able to do one thing great that nobody else can, even if it's only used sparingly. I have no idea what it could be in your campaign if you want to replace mounted archery, but you may want to preserve the flair of being cool the one time it's useful instead of adding something that's good statistically every time.

Comment: Might be good to note that my campaign is a pure dungeon crawler. We don't do anything else, except a bit of character interaction.

Comment: Maybe [Far Shot](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/far-shot-combat---final) could be a good replacement. In a dungeon adventure, it's probably only for that one important shot in the only part of the dungeon that's straight and long enough to use the feat.